# Dual of the multiplication map $m: A \otimes_k A \rightarrow A$, where $A$ is a fin. dim. algebra over a field $k$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a finite dim. $k$-algebra. Let $m:A \otimes_k A \rightarrow A$ be the multiplication map of $A$. Take the dual of this map as follow
$$\delta:=\operatorname{D}(m) : \operatorname{D}(A) \rightarrow \operatorname{D}(A)\otimes_k \operatorname{D}(A),$$
where $\operatorname{D} = \operatorname{Hom}_k (-,k)$.

How is this $\delta$ defined explicitly by using $m$?

Comment: Send $f\in D(A)$ to $f\otimes f\in D(A)\otimes D(A)$?

Comment: @awllower just for completeness: your suggested map can't be right as, for instance, it is not $k$-linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of $D(A)$ are maps $f:A \to k$, and the elements of $D(A) \otimes D(A)$ are maps of the form 
$$
(a,b) \mapsto \sum_i f_i(a)g_i(b), \quad \text{for all } a,b \in A
$$ 
for some $f_i,g_i \in D(A)$.  That is, $D(A) \otimes D(A)$ is the space of all bilinear maps over $A$.
With that: for any $f \in D(A)$, we have
$$
(\delta(f))(a,b) = (f \circ m)(a,b) = f(ab).
$$
So, $\delta$ maps $f \in D(A)$ to the bilinear map $\delta(f): (a,b) \mapsto f(ab)$.

---

Strictly speaking, if we consider $m$ to be a linear function on $A \otimes A$ and we apply the duality functor $D$, then we should find that the target space of $\delta$ should be $D(A \otimes A)$ rather than $D(A) \otimes D(A)$.  With that, we would find that $\delta$ maps $f \in D(A)$ to the unique linear map $\delta(f):A \otimes A \to k$ satisfying $\delta(f): a \otimes b \mapsto f(ab)$.

That being said: because of the universal property that defines tensor products, these two $\delta$'s are the same up to canonical isomorphism.

Comment: And also because of the finite dimension! If $A$ is infinite-dimensional, $D(A\otimes A)$ is not (naturally) isomorphic to $D(A)\otimes D(A)$ (but your solution is still correct, in its second version).

Comment: @CaptainLama I'm pretty sure that there is a natural isomorphism there, even in the infinite dimensional case.  An element of $D(A) \otimes D(A)$ can be canonically identified with a bilinear map from $A \times A$ to $k$. By the universal property, the bilinear map can be canonically identified with a linear functional on $A \otimes A$.  Where did I use finite-dimensionality?

Comment: There is indeed a canonical injection $D(A)\otimes D(A)\to D(A\otimes A)$, given by $f\otimes g\mapsto (a\otimes b\mapsto f(a)g(b))$. But if $A$ is infinite-dimensional, it is not surjective. If we choose a basis $(e_i)$ of $A$ and represent a bilinear map $b$ by its matrix $(b(e_i,e_j))_{i,j}$, then the image of $D(A)\otimes D(A)$ only corresponds to matrices of finite rank.

Comment: @CaptainLama ...and by the universal property, *every* bilinear form is represented in $D(A \otimes A)$. Perfect, thanks for breaking that down.

Comment: I would like to ask that if we take $m: \operatorname{D}(A) \otimes_k \operatorname{D}(A) \rightarrow \operatorname{D}(A)$ as multiplication on $\operatorname{D}(A)$ and take its dual $\delta: A \rightarrow A \otimes_k A$, what could we say in this situation? Could we define explicitly this $\delta$ by using this $m$?

Comment: @Mathalg Your question doesn't make sense.  There is no "multiplication map" that takes a tensor product $f \otimes g$ of linear maps on $A$ and produces another linear map on $A$

Comment: Yes, there is no natural multiplication on $\operatorname{D}(A)$. But there may be an $m$ under some technical assumptions. But I think generally we can not define it by using its dual and a similar way with the main question of this page.

Comment: @Mathalg - I deleted my comment, as it contained an error... (one of the problems of saying anything substantive in comments is that they can be hard to correct!) but still, you might look up Hopf algebras.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment and an addendum on Omnomnomnom's answer, but too long (even longer than the word "Omnomnomnom")... But it's worthwhile, at least just once, to work out a toy example.

Take the $2$-dimensional algebra $A=  k[x]/(x^2)$, i.e., $A=k[x]$, with $x^2 = 0$.

Now, since $D(A)$ is finite dimensional, we can identify $D(A)\otimes D(A)$ with $D(A\otimes A).$ Use the obvious basis $1$ and $x$ for $A$, and consider the dual basis $\epsilon$ and $\lambda$, i.e., $$\text{ $\epsilon(1)=1$, and $\epsilon(x)=0$, and  $\lambda(1)=0$ and $\lambda(x)=1$.}$$ Then $A\otimes A$ has basis 
$$\text{$1\otimes 1$, $x\otimes 1$, $1\otimes x$, $x\otimes x$,}$$ and 
$D(A\otimes A)$ has corresponding dual basis 
$$\text{$\epsilon\otimes \epsilon $,  $\lambda \otimes \epsilon$, $\epsilon \otimes \lambda$,$\lambda \otimes \lambda$.}$$ Since, as "O" above writes, $$(\delta f )(\sum a\otimes b) = \sum f(ab),$$ 
by testing $\delta(\epsilon)$ and $\delta ( \lambda)$ on our $A\otimes A$ basis elements,  we see that 
$$\text{ $\delta(\epsilon) = \epsilon\otimes\epsilon$ and $\delta (\lambda)= \lambda\otimes\epsilon + \epsilon\otimes \lambda $.}$$